# How would I find the top 3 words from a textfile that are next to each other

Tags: algorithm, text

This will be done in python but I would like to know how to approach it.

So say I have a text file with the contents of a book. I don't want to find the top word, I want to find the top 3 words in a row. For example, "The cat opened" is 3 words in a row, "the and is" are the top 3 words.

I can explain further if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file from start to finish, one word at a time. Keep the last three words you read in memory, and increment the key (word1, word2, word3) in a dictionary. If the key didn't exist, initialize it to zero and move on.

When you've walked through the whole text, you walk through the dictionary to find the keys with the highest counter.